# Why does my custom tkinter Combobox not work properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

My custom tkinter comboboxes do not work properly. When i click on the combobox drop down arrow it shows this:

[image: Here is what the combobox shows when i click the drop down arrow first time]

However, when i click on the empty part of the box where the values are meant to be, the values then show. But why cannot it work first time?

Here is the values that show when i do this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU5K0.png)

```
 #nested class is called when the user wants to create a student
    class Student_Details:
        def __init__(self,parent):
            self.parent = parent
            #'parent' is used so nested class can call and inherit any attributes and methods from parent class ('Classes')

            self.creating_Student_Details()#calling function
            self.updating_student_names()#calling function
            self.deleting_student_names()#calling function

        def creating_Student_Details(self):
            #this function creates frame for user to enter students details
            self.createStudentsFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.parent.classFrame)
            self.createStudentsFrame.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3)

            self.create_student_description = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.createStudentsFrame,
                text="Create Student",
                font=ctk.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold")
            )
            self.create_student_description.grid(row=0,column=0)

            self.firstname_Label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.createStudentsFrame,text="First Name")
            self.firstname_Label.grid(row=1,column=0)
            self.firstname_Entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.createStudentsFrame)
            self.firstname_Entry.grid(row=1,column=2)

            self.lastname_Label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.createStudentsFrame,text="Last Name")
            self.lastname_Label.grid(row=2,column=0)
            self.lastname_Entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.createStudentsFrame)
            self.lastname_Entry.grid(row=2,column=2)

            self.save_students_btn = ctk.CTkButton(self.createStudentsFrame, text="Save")
            self.save_students_btn.grid(row=4,column=2)
            self.save_students_btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.students_to_database)
            
            for widget in self.createStudentsFrame.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10)
                #for loop that loops through all widgets
                #all widgets have same amount of padding between them

        def students_to_database(self,event):
            #function is called when user wants to save student to database
            firstname = self.firstname_Entry.get()
            lastname = self.lastname_Entry.get()

            connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            #creates table within database if it has not been created yet.
            createStudentTable = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students
                ([First Name] TEXT,
                [Last Name] TEXT,
                StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE)
                '''
            #making user of primary keys to make links between the tables
            cursor.execute(createStudentTable)

            #code below ensures that the same name cannot be added to database
            #if it does an error message shows
            query_students_table = """SELECT * from Students"""
            cursor.execute(query_students_table)
            fetching_rows = cursor.fetchall()

            flag = False

            for i in fetching_rows:
                if (firstname,lastname) == (i[0],i[1]):
                    flag = True
                    break

            if flag:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "This name already exists!")
            elif firstname=="" or lastname == "":
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "All fields must be entered!")
            else:
                insertClassDetails = '''INSERT INTO
        Students([First Name],[Last Name])VALUES(?,?)'''
                    
                insertToClassTable = (firstname, lastname)
                cursor.execute(insertClassDetails, insertToClassTable)
                connection.commit()
                connection.close()


        #code below is used to update/change a students name

        def updating_student_names(self):
            #function is called so user can change a students name if they made a mistake
            #function creates all labels, frames etc needed
            self.update_name_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.parent.classFrame)
            self.update_name_frame.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.3)

            self.update_name_description = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.update_name_frame,
                text="Update Student Name",
                font=ctk.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold")
            )
            self.update_name_description.grid(row=0,column=0)

            self.original_name = ctk.CTkLabel(self.update_name_frame, text="Update Name:")
            self.original_name.grid(row=6,column=0)
            self.original_name_Options = ctk.CTkComboBox(self.update_name_frame, state="readonly")#, values=self.optionNames)
            self.original_name_Options.bind("<Button-1>", self.names)#binding combobox to function
            self.original_name_Options.grid(row=6,column=1)

            self.change_firstname_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.update_name_frame, text="Change first name to:")
            self.change_firstname_label.grid(row=7,column=0)
            self.change_firstname_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.update_name_frame)
            self.change_firstname_entry.grid(row=7,column=1)

            self.change_lastname_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.update_name_frame, text="Change last name to:")
            self.change_lastname_label.grid(row=8,column=0)
            self.change_lastname_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.update_name_frame)
            self.change_lastname_entry.grid(row=8,column=1)

            self.save_updated_name_btn = ctk.CTkButton(self.update_name_frame, text="Save Updated Name")
            self.save_updated_name_btn.grid(row=9,column=1)
            self.save_updated_name_btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.update_name)#binding button to function

            for widget in self.update_name_frame.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10)
                #for loop that loops through all widgets
                #all widgets have same amount of padding between them

        def names(self,event):
            #function ensures combobox holds all names from database
            connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            #checks to ensures that the students table exists
            #if not it tells te user that they need to enter the students name into the database first
            checking_table_existence = """SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Students'"""
            cursor.execute(checking_table_existence)
            exists = cursor.fetchone()

            if exists:
                query_students = """SELECT [First Name], [Last Name] from Students"""
                cursor.execute(query_students)
                selectingNames = cursor.fetchall()

                optionNames = []
                
                #using for loop to loop through all the names.
                #since my database has 'first name' and 'last name' as different columns I am using the for loop to concatonate the first and last names together.
                #this ensures that the Combobox shows the names together
                for y in selectingNames:
                    optionNames.append(str(y[0])+ str(y[1]))

                self.original_name_Options.configure(values=optionNames) #Combobox now holds the full names of students
                       
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "There are no students to select from!")

                nameTable = "SELECT [First Name], [Last Name] FROM Students" 
                cursor.execute(nameTable)

            

        def students_id(self,event):
            #function is used to get the selected students id
            getting_name = self.original_name_Options.get()

            connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            query_student = """SELECT * from Students"""
            cursor.execute(query_student)
            selecting_rows = cursor.fetchall()

            for i in selecting_rows:
                if getting_name == str(i[0]) + " " + str(i[1]):
                    self.student_id = i[2]
            print(self.student_id)#checking to see if correct id is printed

        def update_name(self,event):
            #function is called so updated name updates in the database
            original_name = self.original_name_Options.get()
            updated_fname = self.change_firstname_entry.get()
            updated_lname = self.change_lastname_entry.get()

            connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            if original_name=="" or updated_fname=="" or updated_lname == "":
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "All fields must be entered!")
            else:
                query_students ="""UPDATE Students SET [First Name]=? , [Last Name]=? WHERE StudentID=?"""

                update_name = (updated_fname, updated_lname, self.student_id)
                cursor.execute(query_students, update_name)
                connection.commit()



        #code below is to delete a student
     
        def deleting_student_names(self):
            #function is called so that it deletes user from database
            #it deletes everything about that student (including test results etc.)
            self.delete_student_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.parent.classFrame)
            self.delete_student_frame.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.3)

            self.delete_description = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.delete_student_frame,
                text="Delete Student",
                font=ctk.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold")
            )
            self.delete_description.grid(row=0,column=0)                
                
            self.delete_student_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.delete_student_frame, text="Delete Student:")
            self.delete_student_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
            self.delete_student_option = ctk.CTkComboBox(self.delete_student_frame, state="readonly")#, values=(self.optionNames))
            self.delete_student_option.grid(row=1,column=1)
            self.delete_student_option.bind("<Button-1>", self.delete_student_list)#binding button to function
            #self.delete_student_option.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.delete_student_id)#function is called when value of combobox changes

            self.delete_student_btn = ctk.CTkButton(self.delete_student_frame, text="Delete")
            self.delete_student_btn.grid(row=2,column=1)
            #self.delete_student_btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.delete_student)

            for widget in self.delete_student_frame.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10)
                #for loop that loops through all widgets
                #all widgets have same amount of padding between them

        def delete_student_list(self,event):
            #code below is used to get the student names from database
            connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            checking_table_existence = """SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Students'"""
            cursor.execute(checking_table_existence)
            exists = cursor.fetchone()

            if exists:
                query_students = """SELECT [First Name], [Last Name] from Students"""
                cursor.execute(query_students)
                selectingNames = cursor.fetchall()

                optionNames = []
                
                #using for loop to loop through all the names.
                #since my database has 'first name' and 'last name' as different columns I am using the for loop to concatonate the first and last names together.
                #this ensures that the Combobox shows the names together
                for y in selectingNames:
                    optionNames.append(str(y[0])+ " " + str(y[1]))
                    
                self.delete_student_option.configure(values=optionNames) #Combobox now holds the full names of students
                
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "There are no students to select from!")

                nameTable = "SELECT [First Name], [Last Name] FROM Students" 
                cursor.execute(nameTable)
```

Comment: Note that `CTkComboBox` mainly contains two parts: the left entry box and the right arrow button.  `CTkComboBox.bind(...)` actually binds the event to the left entry box only.  So clicking the arrow button does not execute the bind callback.

Comment: @acw1668 I see what you mean. How can I bind it to the right arrow button? Is there a way?

Comment: I don't understand why you need the binding at all.  You should populate the combobox when it is being created, not on clicking it.  The right button is for showing the popdown menu when it is clicked, so why do you want to change its function?